# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am iterating through an object and making several requests with items in that object to an API, for fetching data & then sending it to a database. When receiving the data, I am using JSON.parse() to store the json in a variable and sending it to a callback where it is handled and will eventually be sent to a database.

After researching this issue and seeing similar questions here on StackOverflow, I still cannot figure out my issue considering the data from the request is getting parsed fine, but I get the issue a couple minutes after I run my code.

```
async.forEach(players, function(item, callback) {

        var playerAccountId = (item.accountId).replace(/-/gi, '');
        var kills = item.kills;
        var placement = item.placement;

        let options = {
            url: "https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/users/public/br_stats_v2?user_id=" + playerAccountId,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization' : 'c825697ee0b871c684332601b46c2b71'
            }
        };

    // -------------------- //

        function requestData(callback) {
            request(options, function(err, res, body) {
                body = body.trim();
                let json = JSON.parse(body);
                let username = json.data.username;
                return callback(username);

            });
        }

        function doSomething(name) { //Send data directly to database from this callback
            //console.log(name);

            var player = {
                "Name": name,
                "Account ID": playerAccountId,
                "Kills": kills,
                "Placement": placement
            }
            console.log(player);

        }
        requestData(doSomething);
    });
```

After I console.log all the data I get (which is being somewhat parsed correctly considering its being logged), the console gives me the Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 error a couple minutes after I have ran my code. When I console.log(player), there are no issues and there is an object that is logged for each player.

NOTE: I have created another account for this API so that others can test this issue with a authorization id that is not my actual authorization id.

**Error from passing body through callback function and logging it.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com | 524: A timeout occurred</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cf-wrapper">
<div id="cf-error-details" class="cf-error-details-wrapper">
<div class="cf-wrapper cf-error-overview">
<h1>
<span class="cf-error-type">Error</span>
<span class="cf-error-code">524</span>
<small class="heading-ray-id">Ray ID: 4e465e6118edcce2 &bull; 2019-06-09 22:00:24 UTC</small>
</h1>
<h2 class="cf-subheadline">A timeout occurred</h2>
</div>
<div class="cf-section cf-highlight cf-status-display">
<div class="cf-wrapper">
<div class="cf-columns cols-3">
<div id="cf-browser-status" class="cf-column cf-status-item cf-browser-status ">
<div class="cf-icon-error-container">
<i class="cf-icon cf-icon-browser"></i>
<i class="cf-icon-status cf-icon-ok"></i>
</div>
<span class="cf-status-desc">You</span>
<h3 class="cf-status-name">Browser</h3>
<span class="cf-status-label">Working</span>
</div>
<div id="cf-cloudflare-status" class="cf-column cf-status-item cf-cloudflare-status ">
<div class="cf-icon-error-container">
<i class="cf-icon cf-icon-cloud"></i>
<i class="cf-icon-status cf-icon-ok"></i>
</div>
<span class="cf-status-desc">Newark</span>
<h3 class="cf-status-name">Cloudflare</h3>
<span class="cf-status-label">Working</span>
</div>
<div id="cf-host-status" class="cf-column cf-status-item cf-host-status cf-error-source">
<div class="cf-icon-error-container">
<i class="cf-icon cf-icon-server"></i>
<i class="cf-icon-status cf-icon-error"></i>
</div>
<span class="cf-status-desc">fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com</span>
<h3 class="cf-status-name">Host</h3>
<span class="cf-status-label">Error</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
<div class="cf-columns two">
<div class="cf-column">
<h2>What happened?</h2>
<p>The origin web server timed out responding to this request.</p>
</div>
<div class="cf-column">
<h2>What can I do?</h2>
<h5>If you're a visitor of this website:</h5>
<p>Please try again in a few minutes.</p>
<h5>If you're the owner of this website:</h5>
<p><span>The connection to the origin web server was made, but the origin web server timed out before responding. The likely cause is an overloaded background task, database or application, stressing the resources on your web server. To resolve, please work with your hosting provider or web development team to free up resources for your database or overloaded application.</span> <a href="https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171926-Error-524">Additional troubleshooting information here.</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper">
<p>
<span class="cf-footer-item">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong>4e465e6118edcce2</strong></span>
<span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
<span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Your IP</span>: 173.54.204.123</span>
<span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
<span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check for error before attempting to parse http api response

Comment: AFAIK you dont need to use JSON.parse , it should be already parsed due to dataTyp

Answer (score 1):

In your request options, rather than setting the header, you could do:

```
// add `json: true`, and moved the query string to `qs` to automatically encode
let options = {
    url: "https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/users/public/br_stats_v2",
    qs: {
        user_id: playerAccountId
    },
    method: 'GET',
    json: true, // add this
    headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'c825697ee0b871c684332601b46c2b71'
    }
};

// removed json parsing and trimming.
function requestData(callback) {
    request(options, function(err, res, body) {
        let username = body.data.username;
        return callback(username);
    });
}
```

That will automatically convert the response to a JSON object, so you won't have to use `JSON.parse`.

If you still see the same error message, then that would mean there's some problem with the response being returned. In that case, post the `body` or response so we can help.

**Based on your edit**:

You're getting an error page from Cloudflare, which is obviously not valid JSON. So your problem is not JSON parsing, it's the URL you are requesting is incorrect, or you're being rate-limited/blocked.

Comment: I am now getting the error let username = body.data.username;
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Comment: I believe I have found the source of error. When I just passed the body of the response through the callback and logged it, I got the json, but I got an 524 timeout error which was logged as html. The response is way too long to copy and paste. I will post a screenshot of the HTMl response. Would you happen to know what is causing my code to get this 524 timeout error?

Comment: @nhaniph `Cannot read property 'username' of undefined` means the JSON you're parsing is not as you expect. There is no `body.data` and therefore there is no `body.data.username`.